# Jest Test Babel Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm using a very up-to-date *(December 2017)* stack of dependencies. As I try-out isomorphic react tests with Jest, the test suit keeps failing with the following error:

```
* Test suite failed to run
[BABEL] /__tests__/router.test.js: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to
export objects, only functions.
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.35",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^22.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0"
  }
```

.babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have any insights as to why Jest won't run?

Comment: Generally using a mix of Babel 6 and 7 is going to cause issues. What prompted you to use 7 here?

Comment: This is not a production project, babel bridge is meant to cover any issues between 6 and 7. But, yes I agree downgrading we solve this if none knows what is going on.

Comment: "babel bridge is meant to cover any issues between 6 and 7" That is 100% not what it does. It literally just allows Jest to load Babel 7. If you're using Babel 7, you should be using `@babel/preset-react` and such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> babel bridge is meant to cover any issues between 6 and 7

That is 100% not what the bridge package does. All it does is allow tools that use `babel-core` to pass through to `@babel/core`. The entire package is [this single line of code](https://github.com/babel/babel-bridge/blob/a23894936dc6f1b92d7a1067aaa239ce98f0c495/index.js#L2).

If you are using `@babel/core`, you need to use plugins that work on Babel 7. That means `babel-preset-react` should be changed to `@babel/preset-react` and same for `@babel/preset-env` and your `.babelrc` should be:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react",
  ]
}
```

Similarly, `babel-polyfill` should be `@babel/polyfill`.

None of this is well documented yet because Babel 7 is still an unstable beta.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 65):

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
    ],
    "test": [
        "jest"
    ]
}
```

Add the last block of code for "test" to you babel.rc
Here is my .babelrc code for reference

```
   {
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ],
    "test": [
        "jest"
    ]
}
```

Here is my output from the command-line

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.264s
Ran all test suites.
Done in 12.99s.
```

Comment: I wish I could vote up your response about 25 times; I have the feeling it just saved me several hours.  Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: this saved me so much time.

Answer (score 3):

> I met the same challenge while configuring `jest` to work with `babel-6`.

[See complete explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933142/importing-constants-in-jest-tests-with-named-imports/58465904#58465904)

But in summary, this combination of `--devDependencies` worked for me, and i set-up `babel-jest` to transform my `**.js` files:

```
// package.json

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "webpack": "3.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }

// .babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ]
}
```