# Importing `constants` in Jest tests with named imports

Tags: testing, jestjs, jsdom

I have a `config` and `constants` folder in my project. Located in `src\config\test.ts` & `src\constants\index.js` respectively.

I've setup Jest to use `moduleNameMapper` as below so I can just do `import config from 'config'` and `import { SOME_CONST } from 'constants'`

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "config$": "<rootDir>/src/config/test.js",
  "constants$": "<rootDir>/src/constants/index.js"
}
```

However, in my tests any files which use `import { SOME_CONST } from 'constants'` always get an `undefined` value for `SOME_CONST` whereas any which us the default export from `config` work fine.

Is this a known issue? Am I doing something wrong here? can't seem to pin it down.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?
I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu I didn't find a perfect solution but did find a workaround. It seems that `constants` was some kind of reserved import. I changed to `appconstants` both in file and `moduleNameMapper` and things are now working.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as you, but I eventually found this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1641) that addresses it. It looks like `constants` is a core module and therefore evaluated before jest's module mapping. I found [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1641#issuecomment-267517156) which worked for me and says to put this in your test file:

```
jest.mock('constants', () => require('path/to/your/constants'))
```

An alternative is to do what @dougajmcdonald suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777733/dougajmcdonald) above, and rename your webpack alias from `constants` to something else, e.g. `app-constants`.

Answer (score 0):

> I ran into this same challenge too: setting up `jest` with `babel-6`.

Previously, i had worked a lot with the `create-react-app` (CRA) approach. And when i ran into this challenge, deep down i started to really appreciate the awesome work done by the [facebook team](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) in coming up with CRA-tool.

Any ways, this is how i went about tackling this challenge. 
First things first, we need to set the records straight.

> - Accept that configuring these modern JavaScript tools is a hustle, therefore be **patient**
> - [Jest 24](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started) dropped support for **babel-6** (this was my whole challenge, upgrading to babel-7 would come with lots of other changes which i wanted to avoid)
> - There is so much documentation on configuring [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) to work with [babel-7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files), yet so little with with babel-6.

OK, with that out of the way, let's start:

1. I updated my key `dependencies` as advised by the [official jest docs (24.9)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#generate-a-basic-configuration-file) to work with babel-6. And the error of `undefined` upon running tests persisted.

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "jest": "^24.0.0"
}
```

2. I went ahead to `// comment out` some lines to confirm if i would get a remedy but alas i got a more detailed `error` message from jest (at least it was well explained, thanks guys).

> **Screenshot-1**: Commented out `import * as C from ...` statement

[image: Troubleshooting jest/babel errors]

> **Screenshot-2**: Error message from `jest` despite commenting out the `import` constants statement.

[image: Detailed error message from jest]

3. Finally, **this worked**, after lots of "googling" plus trial and error, i finally stumbled upon a working combination of dependencies. Well, given that i kept changing these, i decided to save these as `--devDependencies`, [set-up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest/v/21.2.0) `babel-jest` as a transformer for my `.js` code and updated my `.babelrc` babel config file.

```
// package.json

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "webpack": "3.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }

// .babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@mwamitovi This was probably the best answer i found. i know its weird to see Jest <24 and babel 6, but sometimes you end up working on legacy code.(note: im using vue2.js)

i managed to get this to work by adding the above packages and also `es2015`, like so(jest v23.x, babel 6):

package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "node-notifier": "^10.0.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
}
```

jest.config.js:

module.exports = {
"verbose": true,
"testEnvironment": "jsdom",
"moduleFileExtensions": [
"js",
"json",
"vue"
],
"testMatch": [
"**/**tests**/*.test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
],
"transform": {
".*\.(vue)$": "/node_modules/vue-jest",
".*\.(js)$": "/node_modules/babel-jest"
},
"testURL": "http://localhost/",
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
"node_modules/(?!(p-retry)/)",
]
}

and in your .babelrc

"env": {   "test": {    "presets": [      ["env", {       "modules": alse,       "targets": {         "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 ersions", "not ie <= 8"]       }     }],      "stage-2",      "es2015" ## this is key    ],    "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]   }