# Jest is not running in react project

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I am getting the following error:

> Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In
> ```
>
> D:\final-repo\ISGCustomerPortalClientSide\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js

Any idea as to why Jest won't run ? I read it has something to do with babel, but I didn't manage to grasp as to why.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.4",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "2.26.7",
    "chalk": "2.0.1",
    "concurrently": "3.5.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "coveralls": "3.0.4",
    "css-loader": "3.0.0",
    "enzyme": "3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.12.1",
    "eslint": "4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.3.0",
    "eslint-watch": "5.1.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "0.7.4",
    "history": "4.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.8.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "mock-local-storage": "1.0.5",
    "mockdate": "2.0.1",
    "node": "8.9.4",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "opn-cli": "3.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "prompt": "1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "raf": "3.3.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "2.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.3.0",
    "replace": "1.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "4.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.1.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.22.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6"
  },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Jest Test Babel Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878222/jest-test-babel-error-plugin-preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects)

Comment: you should post your jest.config and the command you run for jest